# How to send custom XMPPPresence Stanzas

Tags: ios, xmpp, offline

I am working on chat app. I wanted to add last seen at functionality. So it thought it can be done via sending custom data with "XMPPPresence" so i tried by below code:

When user "goOffline" then i am sending below stanza.

```
XMPPPresence *presence = [XMPPPresence presenceWithType:@"unavailable"];
NSXMLElement *show = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"show" stringValue:@"away"];

NSXMLElement *status = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"status" stringValue:@"away"];

[presence addChild:show];
[presence addChild:status];

[[self xmppStream] sendElement:presence];
```

When i debug then i checked that i am sending correct value:

```
<presence type="unavailable"><show>away</show><status>away</status><x xmlns="vcard-temp:x:update"><photo/></x></presence>
```

But at other side when i receive the presence then it comes as bellow:

```
<presence xmlns="jabber:client" from="user1@myserver.com/3015805338140183012566044" to="user2@myserver.com/183258723140182997445059" type="unavailable"></presence>
```

So when receiving the presence there is no info regarding status and show tag, Where it goes? Any idea?

And if there is any other better approach to implement last seen functionality then please suggests.

Even i noticed one thing when user goes offline then i am sending same presence as i send on online but still i am getting same response as above. Strange!!!! It should be come out as available when i send available presence on offline

I tried by sending below presence on offline:

```
    XMPPPresence *presence = [XMPPPresence presence]; // type="available" is implicit
[[self xmppStream] sendElement:presence];
```

But i got below in result:

```
<presence xmlns="jabber:client" from="user1@myserver.com/3015805338140183012566044" to="user2@myserver.com/183258723140182997445059" type="unavailable"></presence>
```

Its totally strange as it should come out as available.

Answer (score 0):

Which XMPP server you are using?

If you are using open fire then just sent following stanza:

```c
XMPPPresence *presence = [XMPPPresence presence]; // type="available" is implicit
```

If you are using google or some other third party server then you need to send following stanza on the stream:

```c
XMPPPresence *presence = [XMPPPresence presence]; // type="available" is implicit
NSXMLElement *priority = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"priority" stringValue:@"24"];[presence addChild:priority];

[stream sendElement:presence]
```

This code will make the user as online and all other roster will get update regarding the status of the sender.

Comment: i facing issue only in case of offline presence, i am not getting exact format that i am sending on offline action. More over i am using ejabbered

Comment: For offline please use following code:                 XMPPPresence *presence = [XMPPPresence presenceWithType:@"unavailable"];
 
[stream sendElement:presence];  If it works for you then please do not forget to rate the answer.

Comment: sir its already working, please re read my question carefully

Comment: i want to send status and show tags with "unavailable" tag. how can be do that?

Comment: Did you tried following:         [presence addAttributeWithName:@"status" stringValue:@"Your Custom Message"];

Comment: yes and crash on this, it says not attribute property